# Reduction of Node js docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

I have Node Js Application which is related to Cloud Application Programming Model(CAPM) in SAP.
So I dockerized Node Js Application using below Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4004

CMD npm run dev
```

But it is taking 562MB. Can I reduce this image size. Please help me.

Comment: Do you just copy the build/dist to your image? Also you can run `npm i --production` to install only production related dependencies. After all, your Dockerfile looks more like one for development (?).

Comment: Hello, I followed the process what you said, but it is not reducing size smaller amount like 100MB. For Example I have also React Docker image.  By using Build folder I reduced to 70MB. Is there something related to production build process in Node js. Can you please tell me?